# Tidio not installing in shopify when installed manually by adding script

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I have added one js script before end of the body tag as tidio says in their documentation. But after adding that its not showing the chatbox. I follow as per they say in the doc here [https://help.tidio.com/hc/en-us/articles/5379640857884-Install-Tidio-on-Shopify#:~:text=You%20will%20make%20the%20Tidio,Widget%20and%20save%20the%20changes](https://help.tidio.com/hc/en-us/articles/5379640857884-Install-Tidio-on-Shopify#:%7E:text=You%20will%20make%20the%20Tidio,Widget%20and%20save%20the%20changes).

Let me know if there is any other way in shopify to import modules from url

[image]